# Use ruby methods in javascript without ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby

Is it possible to call a ruby method inside javascript? One way of implementing it is via ajax calls, but is there a way I can embed that ruby function inside the js file and call it just like calling any other js function?

Comment: Yes.  If you're viewing with a browser containing an embedded Ruby runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not without using [Silverlight Dynamic Languages](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/dynamic-languages/) (or similar plugin) to act as a vessel for the language.

Even then, it's not embedding into JS, it's just adding another possible language to the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like [RubyJS](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubyjs/).  This is a port of [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) to Ruby.  Essentially it will let you write Ruby code that is compiled into JavaScript then run in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the JavaScript to run in a web browser: No. Browsers don't have Ruby engines built in.

Answer (score 0):

For Rubyt there was http://hotruby.yukoba.jp/ but it seems like the project stalled.